# FullCalendar change date format

Tags: fullcalendar, date-formatting

When the user select a range of dates on the calendar, a modal opens and the input fields of initial and final dates are auto complete with the dates selected previously. The problem is that they are displaying in this format YYYY-MM-DD and I want it to be DD-MM-YYYY. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work. 
Here is where I get the dates and fill the inputs:

```
select: function (info) {
     $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
     $('#ModalAdd').appendTo("body");
     $('#activoReservar').val($('#selectActivoReserva option:selected').text());
     $('#fechaInicial').val(info.startStr);
     var endDate = new Date(info.end);
     var beforeDay = new Date(endDate.getFullYear(),endDate.getMonth(),endDate.getDate() - 1).toISOString().slice(0,10);
     $('#fechaFinal').val(beforeDay);      
},
```

And here are the things I have tried:

```
$('#fechaInicial').val(info.startStr.format('ddd, DD-MM-YYYY')); //i tried with dd and a single d too. And without any d
$('#fechaFinal').val(beforeDay.format('ddd, DD-MM-YYYY'));
```

Comment: `info.startStr` is a **string** (this is clear from reading https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback). Therefore it does not have a `format()` function you can call. This should be causing an error in your browser's Console. Did you check? FullCalendar has a `formatDate()` function (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/formatDate) which you could use to format a Date object (such as `info.start` instead of `info.startStr`). Or you could use any of the many suggestions you get if you google [javascript format date DD-MM-YYYY](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+format+date+dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may create another function (which you can use anywhere else too),
pass a date to that function and return your desired format.

The sample function might look like as follow:

```
function dateToDMY(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1; //Month from 0 to 11
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d) + '-' + (m <= 9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + y;
}
```

And you may call the function from `select` or any other place as follow:

```
select: function (selectionInfo) {
    var startStr = dateToDMY(selectionInfo.start);
}
```